# Adding headers to an excel file using Java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with adding headers to the newly created .xlsx file
I would like to see the first header = 'UserName' and the second header = 'Password'. Can anyone help me on how to do this?

```
    XSSFWorkbook new_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); // create a blank workbook object
    XSSFSheet sheet = new_workbook.createSheet("EMP_DETAILS"); // create a worksheet with caption score_details

    // Define the SQL query
    String sql = "SELECT login, password FROM \"Permissions\"";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // Create Map for Excel Data
    Map<String, Object[]> excel_data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    int row_counter = 0;
    //Extract data from result set
    while(rs.next()){
        row_counter = row_counter+1;
        String login = rs.getString("login");
        String password = rs.getString("password");
        excel_data.put(Integer.toString(row_counter), new Object[] {login, password});                      
    }
    rs.close();

// Load data into logical worksheet
    Set<String> keyset = excel_data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for(String key : keyset){ // loop through the data and add them to the cell
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object [] objArr = excel_data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for(Object obj : objArr){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if(obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
            else
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("File.xlsx")); // create XLSX file
    new_workbook.write(output_file); // write excel document to output stream
    output_file.close(); // close the file
```

Comment: So, what is your problem actually?

Comment: I would like to excel in the file headers visible
User | Password

Comment: And what is actual result?

Comment: Currently visible
Aloe | 833ue
Tekla | Ufd33

I would like to be visible with headlines, ie
UserName | Password
Aloe | 833ue
Tekla | Ufd33

Comment: example is here: https://www.google.pl/search?q=ADDING+header+in+excel+java&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHw7yFq8DTAhUBDJoKHXjOB2cQ_AUIBygC&biw=1600&bih=766#imgrc=gOfK5Wlv1oP07M:

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02... don't create an Excel file for something this simple. Instead create a CSV file. The first line you write will be

```
UserName, Password
```

for the headers and the lines after that will just be your data for each column separated by a comma. Once the file is written, you can easily open it in Excel and save it as an Excel file.

This method is way simpler and easier than trying to actually write an Excel file.

If you don't want to do that, you just need to create a row before you start looping through your `keyset` as you would any other row and write the strings for headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code after this line `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);`:

ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();

Then to fetch column headers; use below:

```
String columnName1 = rsmd.getColumnName(1); // will fetch you "UserName"
String columnName2 = rsmd.getColumnName(2); // will fetch you "Password"
```